# Is there a way to identify tax row which is added on QuickBooks Canada QBResponse, QB SDK

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

We have QuickBooks Canada version. When we fetch records for Purchase Order it does returns all the records and along with that returns Tax row which is being added by QuickBooks CA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <PurchaseOrderQueryRq requestID="1">
            <TxnID>2304-1229340744</TxnID>
            <IncludeLineItems>1</IncludeLineItems>
            <IncludeLinkedTxns>0</IncludeLinkedTxns>
            <IncludeRetElement>TxnID</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>EditSequence</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>PurchaseOrderLineGroupRet</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>PurchaseOrderLineRet</IncludeRetElement>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
        </PurchaseOrderQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The extra row response has is

```
<PurchaseOrderLineRet>
                            <TxnLineID>2311-1229340744</TxnLineID>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <ListID>490000-1195038595</ListID>
                                <FullName>Summary GST for purchases</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>Total GST</Desc>
                            <Rate>5.0%</Rate>
                            <ClassRef>
                                <ListID>40001-1199213409</ListID>
                                <FullName>Pro Shop:Special orders</FullName>
                            </ClassRef>
                            <Amount>798.00</Amount>
                            <CustomerRef>
                                <ListID>10000-1193777303</ListID>
                                <FullName>Receiver General</FullName>
                            </CustomerRef>
                            <ReceivedQuantity>0</ReceivedQuantity>
                            <IsBilled>false</IsBilled>
                            <IsManuallyClosed>false</IsManuallyClosed>
                        </PurchaseOrderLineRet>
```

Is there a way to identify this row. 
Issue is, if we want to update this order we need to send all the Order line.
And if we send the last line which is of Tax (generated by QB) , QuickBooks SDK throws error.
MLMsgsRs>

```
        <PurchaseOrderModRs requestID="1" statusCode="3120" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="Object &quot;2311-1229340744&quot; specified in the request cannot be found. " />
```

So we need to exclude this line on the PurchaseOrderModRq

Note : Not all Purchase Order's Last line has this tax row.

Answer (score 1):

Export the tax items and compare the Item Refs in the exported PO data against the list of tax items.

Comment: HI, Thanks for sharing. HHHm, that would work only if I don't have any Item which has the same name. In any case normal inventory name matchs the tax name then it could be issue.  Also for each line item I need to do a lookup and see if its tax item or not.

Comment: I think Karl is suggesting to use the ListID values and not the FullName to see if the item on your PO is a tax item or not. I'm not 100% sure about the CA version, but the US edition you can do an ItemSalesTax query to get just the sales tax items.